# Cucumber not working in Intellij Idea: Seems like IDE is not reading plug-ins

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, ide, cucumber

Feature: To verify the functionality og Log In Screen
    Scenario: User will be able to Log In to the account after entering the correct credentials

```
    Given User is on Log In Page
    When User enters Mail ID & Password
    Then User gets the confirmation, "Welcome Back"
```

No Snippets are working, is not creating the stepDefs file on pressing ctrl+space bar.
and the color code is also not as per the IDE Color Theme

Comment: Have you had any updates lately? IntelliJ / Cucumber? Maybe the Intellij Cucumber plugin is not up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your feature file should be aligned as per below format

```
Feature: Login scenario

   Scenario: User will be able to Log In to the account after entering the correct credentials
    Given User is on Log In Page
    When User enters Mail ID & Password
    Then User gets the confirmation, "Welcome Back"
```

Also check support for the Gherkin language, which is used by the Cucumber testing tool along with cucumber java plugin install to support step definitions written in Java.

```
Please check :
1. java properly installed on your machine. 
2. Test Runner class is pointing to glue code package
```

Comment: 1. Well if we use intellij then Intellij follows the same format, but still my IDE wasn't thus I used the same format
2. Java is installed perfectly
3. Test Runner class i also pointed towards glue code package

Comment: can you please cucumber for java and gherkin plugin installed properly